# Unwanted autofill on html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autocomplete, textbox

I am (for the first time) making a signin/register form for a website. For the line in the register form where I ask the user to provide their email address it provides an autofill option, which is fine. The problem is that it also fills in the line below which is where I will get the user to retype the email address to verify it. I have tried using autocomplete="off" but that does not seem to have an affect.

I managed to figure out that if the second email input does not have the word "email" in it the autocomplete does not affect this line. Still tho, autocomplete="off" had no affect and I don't know why. Ideally I would like to have email in the name of this line off code to make it easier to read and similar issues may come up in the future.

Any ideas why this is happening? here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html5>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login or Register</1h>
        <p></p>


        <div id="logindOrRegdiv">
            <input type="button" value="Login" id="login">
            <input type="button" value="Register" id="register">
        </div>

        <div id="logindiv">   
           <form name="login" autocomplete="on">
               Username<input type="text" name="userid"/><br>
               Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/><br>
               <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
               <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
           </form>
           <script language="javascript">
               function check(form) { /*function to check userid & password*/
                   /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
                   if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd") {
                       window.open('target.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
                   }
                   else {
                       alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
                   }
               }
           </script>  
        </div>


        <div id="registerdiv">
            <form name="register" autocomplete="on">
                First Name<input type="text" name="firstname"/><br>
                Middle Name<input type="text" name="middlename"/><br> 
                Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname"/><br> 
                D.O.B.<input type="text" name="dob"/><br>
                Email Address<input type="email" name="email"/><br>
                Re-Type<input type="email" name="email2" autocomplete="off"/><br>
                Password<input type="password" name="password"/><br>
                Re-Type<input type="password" name="password2"/><br>
            </form>         
        </div>

        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html5>
```

Comment: what happens if you add `value=""` in the second email input?

Comment: please tell me that your password checking in this form is done like that for testing

Answer (score 0):

The `autocomplete="off"` attrbute has bugs in most major browsers.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff

The workaround is to give the `name` attribute a random value each time the page is loaded. For example `name="email-jirbcea"`.